# change color of clicked button in CustomListView

Tags: android

I am developing android application and I want to change text color after clicked CustomListView but I want to do save clicked position and When activity is starting change color of clicked button in CustomListView. I try do below code but it doesn't working

```
package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.anket1.R;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    ImageView image;

    ArrayList<Integer> yourSelectedImageArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, Integer[] imageId) {

        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView rank;
        TextView country;
        TextView population;
        ImageView flag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews

        image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        // population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);

        if (yourSelectedImageArray.contains(position)) {

            country.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);

                yourSelectedImageArray.add(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("population",
                        resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));

                intent.putExtra("message", resultp.get(MainActivity.MESAJ));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are not able to do? Save item position or change button's color?

Comment: Save item position in OnClickListener and I want change color of TextView in startActivity

Comment: To change textView's color you simply need to change it inside the onClick method, while reading your code it seems that you are putting your item's position in the extra of your intent. Are you saying that in started activity you can't see the extra?